# Can't install @tensorflow/tfjs-node

Tags: javascript, node.js, tensorflow, npm

I get the following error running `sudo npm install @tensorflow/tfjs-node`:

> `Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir
>   '/home/mike/.../node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-node/build'`

[image]

It says later that this is "probably not an issue with npm" (see screenshot) but gives no indication what the issue could be. I'm not very experienced with npm or nodejs, so I'm not sure what to try. Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

---

**EDIT:** I should mention, I have seen two other posts about this issue on StackOverflow. In one, the user was on Windows, which tfjs-node doesn't support, and I'm on Ubuntu. In the other, the user was using a version of Node.js that was too old; I am using 10.6.

Comment: How did you install Node.js on your system? Also, why are you installing as the root user? That's going to lead to problems if you aren't careful, I recommend using Node.js as a normal user in most circumstances.

Comment: Using the instructions for Ubuntu [here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions). Well I was getting a permissions error that I reported above, so I thought using sudo may resolve it. Can you elaborate what problems that could cause, and why you generally recommend using Node.js as normal user?